# How to implement the Accumulator interface

Tags: java, generics, lambda, interface, testunit

Task: Create class IntegerAccumulator that implements Accumulator that passes the test unit

The code that I've tried below is not working because the test unit only uses 1 parameter when using the add method. The error code that I'm getting is mostly due to the parameters.

I've tried:

```
class IntegerAccumulator implements Accumulator{
    void add(Function function, DataStrore store){

    }

    T getResult(){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here are the provided codes:
Main:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(final String[] argv)
    {
        final DataStore<Integer> intStore;
        final DataStore<String> strStore;
        final Accumulator<Integer, Integer> intAccumulator;
        final Accumulator<String, String> strAccumulator;

        intStore = new MemoryDataStore<>(1, 3);
        intStore.setValueAt(0, 0, 10);
        intStore.setValueAt(0, 1, 200);
        intStore.setValueAt(0, 2, 3);

        strStore = new MemoryDataStore<>(1, 3);
        strStore.setValueAt(0, 0, "Hello");
        strStore.setValueAt(0, 1, "Evil");
        strStore.setValueAt(0, 2, "World");

        intAccumulator = new IntegerAccumulator();
        intAccumulator.add((value) -> value, intStore);
        System.out.println(intAccumulator.getResult());

        strAccumulator = new StringAccumulator();
        strAccumulator.add((value) -> value, strStore);
        System.out.println(strAccumulator.getResult()); // Hello, Evil, World

        strStore.setValueAt(0, 0, "Bye");
        strStore.setValueAt(0, 1, null);
        strStore.setValueAt(0, 2, "Bye!"); // Hello, Evil, World, Bye, , Bye!

        strAccumulator.add((value) -> value, strStore);
        System.out.println(strAccumulator.getResult());
    }
}
```

```
public interface Accumulator<D, T>
{
    void add(Function<D, T> function, DataStore<D> store);
    T getResult();
}
```

```
public interface DataStore<T>
{
    void setValueAt(int row, int col, T value);
    T getValueAt(int row, int col);
    int getRows();
    int getCols();
}
```

```
class IntegerAccumulatorTest
{
    @Test
    void add()
    {
        final IntegerAccumulator a;
        final IntegerAccumulator b;

        a = new IntegerAccumulator();
        b = new IntegerAccumulator();
        assertThat(a.getResult(), equalTo(0));
        assertThat(b.getResult(), equalTo(0));

        a.add(1);
        assertThat(a.getResult(), equalTo(1));
        assertThat(b.getResult(), equalTo(0));

        a.add(1);
        assertThat(a.getResult(), equalTo(2));
        assertThat(b.getResult(), equalTo(0));

        a.add(3);
        assertThat(a.getResult(), equalTo(5));
        assertThat(b.getResult(), equalTo(0));

        a.add(null);
        assertThat(a.getResult(), equalTo(5));
        assertThat(b.getResult(), equalTo(0));

        a.add(-6);
        assertThat(a.getResult(), equalTo(-1));
        assertThat(b.getResult(), equalTo(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: So your main works with `intAccumulator.add((value) -> value, intStore);`. Do you see any difference to the non-working unit-test using `a.add(1);` (e.g. passing int-value `1` instead of a _functional_ like `(value) -> value`; or missing second parameter for the _datastore_) ? The _datastore_ is an the source where accumulator reads its values from in order to accumulate to a result.

Comment: Yes, I've tried changing the Main class and it is throwing error when lacks one parameter.

Comment: Test, implementation `IntegerAccumulator` and interface `Accumulator` currently don't fit together. Which one is given as fix by your task? You need to adjust at least one to work!

Comment: the given is Test, and Accumulator interface. IntegerAccumulator is the one I need to create to fit both Test and Accumulator.

Comment: Not it's clear. And you tied to implement the `IntegerAccumulator` ... can you post your code for that (even if it's not working) as [example]. I am sure we will get it working 

Comment: thank you ! that's the farthest i've gone so far. Even the test didn't use the datastore.

Comment: Matt, curious to know: Who gave you the task? Is this your first interface implementation or are you new to Java ?
__First to learn on SO__: Please always post `the error code` you got !! We can not help you, if we don't can reproduce the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your task(s) as understood from question & comments:

- implement the given interface `Accumulator` as `IntegerAccumulator`
- make the given test passing

#### Interface to implement:

```java
public interface Accumulator<D, T>
{
    void add(Function<D, T> function, DataStore<D> store);
    T getResult();
}
```

This interface needs to be implemented by  The interface is *generic* which means it has *type-parameter*  (placeholders `D` could stand for *data* as input; `T` could stand for *total* as result). Both type-parameters need to be defined by concrete types (like `Integer` or `String`) when implemented by a *concrete* class.

#### Test to pass (excerpt only):

```java
class IntegerAccumulatorTest
{
    @Test
    void add()
    {
        final IntegerAccumulator a;
        final IntegerAccumulator b;

        a = new IntegerAccumulator();
        b = new IntegerAccumulator();
        assertThat(a.getResult(), equalTo(0));
        assertThat(b.getResult(), equalTo(0));

        a.add(1);
        assertThat(a.getResult(), equalTo(1));
        assertThat(b.getResult(), equalTo(0));

        // further code omitted
    }

}
```

Note that this test is not verifying the interface completely. Only one method `getResult` is tested, the other `add(1)` differs from the interface. So it must be implemented in order to pass, although not part of the interface.

#### Solving the test

```java
class IntegerAccumulator implements Accumulator<Integer, Integer> {

    // needed to store the result
    private int total = 0;

    void add(Function function, DataStrore store){
      // TODO: needs to be implemented to make `main` work
      // not verified in unit-test
    }

    /**
     * Should return the result as accumulation of previously added data.
     */
    @Override
    Integer getResult(){
        return this.total;
    }

    /**
     * Is verified by the unit-test, although not part of the interface {@link Accumulator}.
     */
    @Override
    public void add(int value) {
      this.total += value;
    }
}
```

Now your test should go green signaling it has been passed by your implementation.
But the main program might still not work correctly (`main` may not print expected comments), since the interface is not fully implemented yet.

#### Next steps: to make `main` work correctly

You might have to:

- implementing the interface completely
- and .. what about the *accumulator for `String`s* used in the main method?
- follow the debendent collaborators: for both we also need to implement the interface `DataStore`

All of the above implementations couldn't be added as separate classes. Thus loosing the benefit of being independent (loosely coupled). So you can't add and remove as you like. Instead you must edit/change existing code.

You could either modify the `main` method to implement the interfaces as **anonymous class** (e.g. directly at their `final` declaration).
Or edit your `interface Accumulator` directly to implement the method stubs as **`default` implementations**.

Using `default` methods within interfaces is a new feature since Java 8.
It can even make your previous implementation obsolete, since you don't have to override to put behavior to the interface methods (it will automatically use the `default` methods defined).

See this tutorial on [default methods](https://www.baeldung.com/java-static-default-methods)

Comment: Not sure if I put the annotations right. If you have an IDE at hand, can you please test the implementation.